# Flutter Firebase: how to update user in UI

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, stream, stream-builder

I want my App's UI to update whenever I change something about the currently signed in `User`, such as changing the `displayName` property. As you can see, I am using a `StreamProvider` and the `Stream<User>` object which is returned by `FirebaseAuth.instance.idTokenChanges()`.
Is there a way for me to manually (I mean from my code) add a new event to that Stream, so that the whole UI of the app updates?

```
//Somewhere at the top of my app I have this widget:
class FirebaseAuthWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: AuthHelper.userStream,
      initialData: AuthHelper.currentUser,
      child: App(),
    );
  }
}


class AuthHelper {
  static final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  static User get currentUser => _auth.currentUser;
  static Stream<User> get userStream => _auth.idTokenChanges();

  //...

  static Future<void> updateDisplayName(String newDisplayName) async {
    await currentUser.updateDisplayName(newDisplayName);
    //TODO how do I get the updated user object (with the updated displayName) to show in UI?
  }

  //...

}
```

Note: I HAVE solved this, but with a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75548742/flutter-how-do-i-add-event-to-existing-stream#answer-75570501). What I want to know is, is there a simpler, more straight-forward way of solving my problem?

Comment: Instead of `FirebaseAuth.instance.idTokenChanges`, try `FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges`, see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/start#userchanges). Although I am not sure it will be fired on display name changes...

Comment: You are welcome, so does it fire on `updateDisplayName`? The docs are confusing, earlier it fired on `updateProfile` which is deprecated as of now.

Comment: if I understood your question correctly, yes, whenever I call updateDisplayName, I notice my whole app rebuilding (bc of the StreamBuilder), it is also confirmed by print statements

Comment: Great, thanks, that's what I asked.

Comment: @PeterKoltai To bring closure to this question, can you post the gist of what that documentation describes as an answer and explain why that solves OP's problem?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Sure thing, I posted an answer. The Firebase documentation is outdated concerning `updateProfile` since this is deprecated in the most recent version.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I created a PR to update the documentation, [see here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-docs/pull/6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FirebaseAuth.instance.idTokenChanges()` executes in the following cases, see [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/start#idtokenchanges):

> Events are fired when the following occurs:
>
> - Right after the listener has been registered.
> - When a user is signed in.
> - When the current user is signed out.
> - When there is a change in the current user's token.

As you see, this does not include changes in `displayName` property. But there is another method which you can use, `FirebaseAuth.instance.userChanges()`, see [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/start#userchanges). With this you can listen to the following changes:

> Events are fired when the following occurs:
>
> - Right after the listener has been registered.
> - When a user is signed in.
> - When the current user is signed out.
> - When there is a change in the current user's token.
> - When the following methods provided by FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser are called:
>
>   - reload()
>   - unlink()
>   - updateEmail()
>   - updatePassword()
>   - updatePhoneNumber()
>   - updateProfile()

Now the documentation seems to be outdated, since `updateProfile` is deprecated in the most recent version of Firebase tools. The deprecation warning says:

> Use updatePhotoURL and updateDisplayName instead.

Based on the comment from the author of OP, it is confirmed that `userChanges` is called when `updateDisplayName` is executed, so this solves the problems. In your code, instead of this:

```
static Stream<User> get userStream => _auth.idTokenChanges();
```

use this:

```
static Stream<User> get userStream => _auth.userChanges();
```